# Servicestack routing issue with 'Could not find property' error

Tags: c#, json, routes, servicestack

When I upgreade the servicestack version of my application to "4.5.12", i am getting error as decribed below.

First of all my application configuration is something like this basicly:

```
[Route("/users/{Id}")]
public class User : IReturn<UserResponse>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class UserResponse
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }

}

public class MyServices : Service
{
    public object Any(User request)
    {
        return new UserResponse { Id = request.Id, Name = request.Name, Surname = "Unknown"};
    }
}
```

If i call service like this:
[http://localhost:24365/users/1?format=json][1]

I am getting error:

```
{
"ResponseStatus": {
    "ErrorCode": "ArgumentException",
    "Message": "Could not find property Id on User",
    "StackTrace": "   konum: ServiceStack.Host.RestPath.CreateRequest(String pathInfo, Dictionary`2 queryStringAndFormData, Object fromInstance)\r\n   konum: ServiceStack.Host.RestHandler.CreateRequest(IRequest httpReq, IRestPath restPath, Dictionary`2 requestParams, Object requestDto)\r\n   konum: ServiceStack.Host.RestHandler.CreateRequest(IRequest httpReq, IRestPath restPath, Dictionary`2 requestParams)\r\n   konum: ServiceStack.Host.RestHandler.CreateRequest(IRequest httpReq, IRestPath restPath)\r\n   konum: ServiceStack.Host.RestHandler.ProcessRequestAsync(IRequest httpReq, IResponse httpRes, String operationName)"
}
```

}

But i have "Id" property in "User" model. Is there anyone have a problem like this?

Answer (score 2):

I checked github for reason of this error on [github(line:425)](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Host/RestPath.cs).

I think line:417 causes this error.

```
if (!this.propertyNamesMap.TryGetValue(variableName.ToLower(), out propertyNameOnRequest))
```

Because "I" and "i" not same character for our pc language. (Culture: tr-TR)

For fixing problem i have to add some codes to apphost.cs file like this:

```
public class AppHost : AppHostBase
{
    public override RouteAttribute[] GetRouteAttributes(Type requestType)
    {
        var routes = base.GetRouteAttributes(requestType);
        routes.Each(x => x.Path = x.Path.ToLower(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")));
        return routes;
    }
}
```